# how to parse custom json array list in kotlin using GSON

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin, gson

this is my data class, need to parse the arraylist of type link

```
class DetailResponse {
    data class BasicInfo (
        @SerializedName("favorite") val isFavorite: Boolean,
        @SerializedName("screenshots") val screenshots: ArrayList<Link>
    )

    data class Link (
        @SerializedName("href") val href: String
    )
}
```

Comment: Your question does not describe your problem statement, can you try being more elaborative as to what you want

Comment: my json tree is nested as above  mentioned ,i want the arraylist of screenshots

Comment: And where is your json?

Comment: Kindly share your json.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. Now you just have to use Gson to convert this JSON to object

```
val gson = Gson()
val detailResponse = gson.fromJson(resp,DetailedResponse::class.java)
```

where "resp" is your json string.